# How to read Configuration data from a HttpClient helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In my Blazor Server Application, I'm trying to read configuration data from `appsettings.json` from within a helper class that is used for configuring an `HttpClient` service to call a web API.
In my `Program.cs` file, I'm adding the `HttpClient` service as:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyHelper>();
```

I need to access the App configuration inside my Helper class, which is as follows:

```
public class MyHelper
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyHelper(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;    
       
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
            HeaderNames.ContentType, "application/json");

        //Read configuration from appsettings.json

        );    
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may inject **IConfiguration** to access the **appsettings.json** contents.

```
public class MyHelper
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyHelper(HttpClient httpClient,IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;

       
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.ContentType, "application/json");

        //Read configuration from appsettings.json
        
        var connection=  configuration["connectionString"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change the line in my Program.cs file, since the constructor parameters are changed?

Comment: It'll be automatically resolved during DI, if you are manually creating an instance you can pass builder.Configuration for the second parameter.